# How best to reduce primary key value?

Tags: .net, informix

I am developing an application (.Net) that supports Oracle, Sql Server and Informix as the data repositories. A problem with Informix is that one table (this is legacy stuff) has a primary key of 2048 characters, and Informix will not allow a PK of this width. So my initial solution is to get the app to derive an MD5 value from the key value and use that as the primary key when inserting or looking up data. Okay that works, but leaves me the immediate problem of 'upgrading' the data in existing databases, which for various reasons has to be done by means of a Sql script.  Sadly Informix does not have a built-in MD5 function so I will be hard pressed to write a Sql script to create the new PK column and populate it from the existing data.

So my question is: can anyone suggest a better way of significantly compressing a long string value, that will avoid this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Informix, if you create a dbspace with large page sizes (you'd need to use 12, 14 or 16 KiB pages), you can create indexes on keys up to about 3 KiB in that dbspace (rule of thumb, 5 key values must fit on one index page).

But a key that big is probably not very efficient, to be polite about it.  I'd be curious to see the breakdown of the columns in the PK and why they have to be so big that they add up to 2 KiB.  Can you not use a surrogate of some sort?

Comment: Thanks. It turns out that my limited understanding of Informix was the real problem - I just have to instruct the DBA to use an appropriate page size and my key-size-limit problem goes away. I must confess I was more than a little surprised when I hit the key-size limit, but just accepted it at the time.

Comment: a PK that large is still very inefficient!.. can you share with us what your PK's all about?.. it sounds like it has alot of text in it!.. there are ways of generating unique keys smaller than 120 chars from a 2K column.

Comment: can you extract needed substrings from the 2K data to create a smaller unique PK or is the full 2K needed to uniquely identify a row?

Comment: It's a 'translation' table, where the key is the piece of text to be translated, and the lookup is the translation. Not my design but there it is and I can't change it. That's why the PK column is so wide.

Answer (score 5):

Your approach is flawed as a PK must be definition be unique, and MD5 may generate collisions (duplicates).

Instead consider using a surrogate PK (e.g. identity or GUID).

> can anyone suggest a better way of significantly compressing a long string value, that will avoid this problem

By definition you can't compress arbitrary strings and maintain uniqueness.  Obviously if the strings have some structure that you know about, you could use this knowledge to create an application-specific compression algorithm.

In response to comments:

> I also have a problem with surrogate keys, which bear no relation to the date being stored - bad database design

I know surrogate vs natural keys is a contentious subject, but surely your proposed MD5 hash is essentially a surrogate key?  And in any case "all design is trade-off" so I wouldn't describe a database design as "bad" without some context.  IMHO if there is no 
natural key shorter than 2048 characters, a surrogate key may well be a good option.

There are also performance tradeoffs to consider: with an MD5 or GUID surrogate PK, you have the potential for page splits as new rows will be inserted in the middle of the table vs at the end for an Identity PK.

> By what definition?

The key word is 'arbitrary'.  A non-lossy compression algorithm such as ZIP does not guarantee to achieve a given compression ratio on all inputs - think of attempting to ZIP a ZIP archive.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, but according to my research in practice the probability of collisions using MD5 is vanishingly small. I would rather risk this than run the risk of duplicate values by not having a primary key, which is another option. I also have a problem with surrogate keys, which bear no relation to the date being stored - bad database design.

Comment: "By definition you can't compress arbitrary strings and maintain uniqueness". By what definition? Are you sure of this? Given that the compression algorithm is reversible, surely a compressed version of a unique value must itself be unique (otherwise how would it be reversible)? An algorithm such as gzip cannot generate duplicate collisions or file compression would simply not work.

Comment: If you define "compress" as always reducing the size, then Joe is correct; "compressing" and "unique" are mutually exclusive by the pigeonhole principle. Gzip and such get around this by not guaranteeing that the "compressed" data is smaller, it may in fact be larger. Joe is not suggesting not using a primary key, he is suggesting using a surrogate PK. Why use a method whose probability of collisions is "vanishingly small" when you can use one where it is zero?

Comment: When your problem is a table with a CHAR(2048) PK column, it takes chutzpah to call use of surrogate keys "bad database design" :-)

Comment: Well thank you for that. :-) 
Not to use a surrogate key is good database design because (I refer you to Codd on this) the primary key should be a property of the data itself, and of that data, the thing that makes each row of data unique from all other rows, just happens to be long strings....to be continued...

Comment: Awkward, but that's the real world for you. I understand the performance implication of this which is why I am searching for a way to provide another key value which has a one to one relationship with the long data it replaces as the key - ie something smaller that uniquely identifies the row of data. A surrogate key (by which I mean an arbitrary value like an identity column or a GUID) does not have that relationship and so will not prevent duplication of the actual data, which is the main purpose of a key and why IMHO that is always bad database design. ..to be continued....

Comment: So my thought was that using MD5 or similar might give sufficient 'uniqueness' to work in practice, or perhaps use a compression algorithm to reduce the size of the key value whilst retaining the notion that the key is based on the real data - or perhaps find a better way of achieving the same. ...to be continued...

Comment: It turns out however that my limited understanding of Informix was the real problem - I just have to instruct the DBA to use an appropriate page size and my key-size-limit problem goes away. Thanks to whoever explained that (in another answer) for doing so. I must confess I was more than a little surprised when I hit the key-size limit, but just accepted it at the time

Comment: "the primary key should be a property of the data itself..." @user463939, that is the opposite of correct, and if you think Codd's rules mean that you should read Codd's ACM Transactions on Database Systems, Vol. 4, No. 4, December 1979 article, pages 409 - 410, where he specifically states the problems with natural keys and proposes surrogate keys to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can split key on two parts and store that parts in two columns, something like "id1", "id2". And then you can create composite primary key.

Comment: Regrettably that won't work - the limitation in Informix is on the key width, not column width. The number of key columns is irrelevant